# cannot find package google.golang.org/grpc

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go, go-packages

When I try to import the grpc package I get the following error:

```
could not import google.golang.org/grpc (cannot find package "google.golang.org/grpc" in any of 
    /usr/local/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOROOT)
    /home/ansh/Go/src/google.golang.org/grpc (from $GOPATH))
```

This is my gopath (incase it helps):

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/Go"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin"
```

I did install these two packages:

```
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.26
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1
```

But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: You shouldn't need to rely on GOPATH anymore. Use go modules. Try reading [Get started with Go](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started) and take notice of the use of the **`go mod`** tool. Other useful articles: [Create a Go module](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module) and [Using Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using go modules, there is no need to set `GOPATH` anymore. However if `GOPATH` is set and you want to use a package from your project directory you need to set `GO111MODULE=off`, because by default `GO111MODULE` is set as `ON`. So even if the package `google.golang.org/grpc` is in your `GOPATH` you will have to force Go not to use the Go modules.

So something like this should work in case you are still opting of using `GOPATH`.

```sh
$ GO111MODULE=off && go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v1.26
$ GO111MODULE=off && go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@v1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined a go.mod file yet, please run the "`go mod init ...`" command to create it.
Then run the following command:
`go get -u google.golang.org/grpc`

Answer (score -1):

in case grpc with updated gopath, dependencies will be looking gopath
Step1 : create go mod file in base folder of the project
"go mod init"
Step2 : run
"go mod tidy"
which loads the dependencies to "go.sum"